# Sheets - Return every cell which contains a string from another sheet

Tags: database, google-sheets

I am currently trying to find a way to show what classes are in what rooms in a school via Google Sheets.

I have made a staff overview on which classes are where and taught by who. The data set is quite clean with every class code being 5 characters long and each room being 4.

Below is a link to an example sheet and snippets from the database along with preferred results:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H9Q8K9KBLgqCsvVZ_ekqsLPbZKeMzvldDnyI-KerOD4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 REGEXREPLACE(B3:F10, "(@)", "("&TRIM(A3:A10)&"),$1")&","), "@")), 
 "select max(Col1) where Col2 <>',' and Col2 is not null 
  group by Col1 pivot Col2"),,9^9)), ",")))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, this does show what classes are being taught by who and where. But this does not show when! If you look at the preferred results you can see what I mean.